# 64 byte cache block and memory overhead for cachline with 7 states (3 bits)

Tags: cpu-cache, cache

I came across some lecture notes of a professor about memory consistency and models. There is an example about memory overhead:

The cache line has 7 states (3 bits): unowned, shared, exclusive, modified, read, update and "uncached read".

- For 64 processor with the cache line described above, the memory
  overhead is 12.5%
- For 256 processor with the cache line described above, the memory
  overhead is 50%
- For 1024 processor with the cache line described above, the memory
  overhead is 200%.

This is the only information that I received from the notes. I wanted to ask him by contacting him but I got no answer. How are these overheads calculated?

Comment: @D.W. I did not write "memory head". I said "memory overhead". I am not sure what memory head is in the lecture notes.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the wrong thing.  Please [edit] the question to define what you mean by "memory overhead".  It's not clear to me what exactly that might refer to.  It might be hard to answer this question without more context from the lecture notes.  Can you link to them?

Comment: @D.W. I do not have a link but I can upload it somewhere. Is there any online platform that you could recommend me to upload into?